# Optimizing Multiple Canvases in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, canvas, optimization, html5-canvas

#### Some Background

I have a web page that is designed to preview multiple animated canvases (we will a single canvas a "project"). The animations are created in Adobe Animate and exported to canvas (there is limited to no alteration to the exported files after the export is complete). My page prints out a list of "projects" which are being displayed through an iFrame.

#### The Problem

When the page loads a single project, everything runs smoothly and at a good frame rate. The problem I am having, is that when many (5+, upwards of 12) projects are loaded, the frame rate drops significantly. I am looking for an optimization that will help improve the frame rate of these projects in a way that could be a "catch all" type solution, meaning that all projects can take this optimization and perform as expected.

Ideally my solution would be either one or both of the following:

- an snippet that can easily be copy/pasted into each project after export
- an optimization that can be done on my page that will alter how the canvases run their animations

Comment: Sounds like 12 simultaneous animations are too many. Perhaps `stop` all the animations and only `play` or `gotoAndPlay` the animations when the user hovers over a particular frame.

Comment: I considered a solution like that, but I don't think I will have access to any of the scripts from the canvas because they are inside the iFrame. Is that even possible?

Comment: If each project handles the animation by itself it creates overhead and might trigger several repaint per frame. First thing to do would be to run all animations from a single loop. Maybe adobe provides tools to run several animations at once...

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what is happening, but one of my drawbacks is that each project needs to also run stand alone outside of the context of this page. This page is really just a way to preview a bunch of animations. They are not necessarily a package and will not be together at all times. It's a good thought to check Adobe's settings, maybe there is a way I can change how we export; somehow I did not consider that option.